# How to trigger an event tag when a user leaves a page?

Tags: google-analytics, dom-events, google-tag-manager, eventtrigger, event-tracking

In Google Tag Manager, I'm tracking the `pageScrollDepth` variable.
I want to trigger a Google Analytics event Tag that pushes (as custom metrics) the recent value of `pageScrollDepth` just before the user leaves the page.

How can I create the `leavingPage` trigger?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2014/04/scroll-depth-tracking-analysis-google-analytics

^ The code in this blog post is the one that your are looking for where it takes the last scroll depth before the user leaves to another page. You will find a link to bitbucket to download the code

Paste the code in a Custom HTML tag and then create a JS variable to call the "callbackData.scrollPercent" for the Event Label